# Migration from servant-0.4.4.7 to servant-0.7.1

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai, servant

I used the `servant-0.4.4.7`. Below is my model code:

```
type API = ServletAPI :<|> Raw

type AppM = ReaderT Config (EitherT ServantErr IO)

runApplication :: IO ()
runApplication = do 
    configApp <- initializationConfig
    case configApp of
        ConfigNull  -> return ()
        otherwise   -> run (opt_portServer . cfg_optionsArg $ configApp) $ app configApp

app :: Config -> Application
app configApp = serve api (readerServer configApp)

readerServer :: Config -> Server API
readerServer configApp = enter (readerToEither configApp) server
                    :<|> serveDirectory (opt_pathFolderStatic . cfg_optionsArg $ configApp)

readerToEither :: Config -> AppM :~> EitherT ServantErr IO
readerToEither configApp = Nat $ \x -> runReaderT x configApp

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy
```

This code worked.But when I use `servant-0.7.1`, I get the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Except.ExceptT
                           ServantErr IO’
                   with ‘EitherT ServantErr IO’
    arising from a functional dependency between:
      constraint ‘Servant.Utils.Enter.Enter
                    (ReaderT Config (EitherT ServantErr IO) Data.Text.Internal.Text)
                    (AppM :~> EitherT ServantErr IO)
                    (Control.Monad.Trans.Except.ExceptT
                       ServantErr IO Data.Text.Internal.Text)’
```

I understand that there is a type mismatch, but how to fix it, I can not understand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing all `EitherT`s to `ExceptT`s (from `Control.Monad.Trans.Except` in `transformers`) should do the trick. `EitherT` came from the `either` package, which has been folded into `transformers` (under the name `ExceptT`), so `servant`, along with more and more packages, migrated to `ExceptT`.

Comment: Thank you very mach! I tried to like according [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279943/using-servant-with-readert-io-a), but had any errors!